# How long does it take to run scipy.test('full')?

Tags: python, testing, numpy, scipy

After I installed numpy and scipy on Windows 7, I have run tests.
`numpy.test('full')` finished quickly, but `scipy.test('full')` just stuck there without any errors.

So, how long does it takes to run `scipy.test('full')`?

Comment: So, how long did you wait. The tests can take tens of minutes to finish.

Comment: I waited for one hour.

Comment: Well, that depends on lots of things - your hardware, your OS, the version of scipy you are testing, the BLAS library it's linked to etc. It takes about 8mins on my quad core laptop (running Ubuntu 14.04, scipy v0.13.3, linked against OpenBLAS). For comparison, `numpy.test('full')` takes about 3min (numpy v1.8.1).

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a Macbook Pro 15" with OSX 10.10.4 with the following package versions.

```
Running unit tests for scipy
NumPy version 1.9.2
NumPy is installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy
SciPy version 0.15.1
SciPy is installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy
Python version 2.7.10 (default, Jun 10 2015, 19:42:47) [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53)]
nose version 1.3.4
...
```

- `python -c "import scipy; scipy.test()"`: 140.15 real       164.13 user        35.81 sys
- `python -c "import scipy; scipy.test('full')"`: 640.63 real       686.81 user        32.79 sys

> [Others](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_centos6.html?highlight=check_blas#test-the-newly-installed-packages) say `scipy.test()` takes up to 1 minute.